# face recognition in flutter using open cv python

Tags: python, flutter, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to build face recognition project in mobile apps using flutter. From backend side, I use open cv from python, so there is `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to open webcam, the thing that makes me confused is.. is it possible to open camera device from mobile apps using `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` ? or is there a right way to open camera device from flutter and connect it with backend to do face recognition?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this

Comment: @DanielSogbey no I haven't find the solution yet